# golang net/smtp getting smtp server response DSN

Tags: email, go, smtp

I am using golang net/smtp to send mails

Whenever I send to my smtp server I need to capture the response from the server 
Especially the DSN

For example my local smtp server gives a "ok queued as "  at the end of the mail

I need to capture this and print in the logs

How can I do this

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/smtp"
)

func sendEmail(msg []byte) {
    c, err := smtp.Dial("localhost:25")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := c.Mail("sender@example.org"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := c.Rcpt("recipient@example.net"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    wc, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err = wc.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //How do I get the response here ??
    err = wc.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = c.Quit()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't find anything about it. But I wonder if the underlying conn can be consumed.

Comment: I have a suggestion. If you look closely the [Client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#Client) has an exported field named `Text`. The `Text` type contains one important [embedded](https://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/#Conn) type name `Reader` and you can actually read the response with [it](https://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/#Reader.ReadResponse).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `c.Text.ReadResponse()`:

```
package main

import (
    "net/smtp"
)

func sendEmail(msg []byte) (code int, message string, err error) {
    c, err := smtp.Dial("localhost:25")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer c.Quit() // make sure to quit the Client

    if err = c.Mail("sender@example.org"); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if err = c.Rcpt("recipient@example.net"); err != nil {
        return
    }

    wc, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer wc.Close() // make sure WriterCloser gets closed

    _, err = wc.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    code, message, err = c.Text.ReadResponse(0)
    return
}
```

---

The `code`, `message` and any `err` are now passed to the caller, don't use `log.Fatal` throughout your code, handle the error on the calling side.

Comment: No that does work 

This is what I tried 

 _, message, err := c.Text.ReadResponse(0)
 fmt.Printf("Response = %s\n", message)   // hangs for ever

Comment: After going through the library I realized. 
The underlying net/smtp module implements the Close to throwaway the DSN 

Is there some other library I can use

Comment: @Ram - if it's hanging, you're already read the response and waiting for more data.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "net/smtp"
)

func sendEmail(msg []byte) (code int, message string, err error) {
    c, err := smtp.Dial("localhost:25")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer c.Quit() // make sure to quit the Client

    if err = c.Mail("sender@example.org"); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if err = c.Rcpt("recipient@example.net"); err != nil {
        return
    }

    wc, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    _, err = wc.Write(msg)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    code, message, err = closeData(c) 
    if err != nil {
        return 0, "", err
    }
    
    return code, message, err
}


func closeData(client *smtp.Client) error {
    d := &dataCloser{
        c:           client,
        WriteCloser: client.Text.DotWriter(),
    }

    return d.Close()
}

type dataCloser struct {
    c *smtp.Client
    io.WriteCloser
}

func (d *dataCloser) Close() (int, string, error) {
    d.WriteCloser.Close() // make sure WriterCloser gets closed
    code, message, err := d.c.Text.ReadResponse(250)

    fmt.Printf("Message %v, Error %v\n", message, err)
    return code, message, err
}
```